# How arraylist perserve data after serialization

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

When checking **java.util.ArrayList** implementation notice that element data object array in side the arrayList is **transient** even though ArrayList is serializable.

```
transient Object[] elementData; // non-private to simplify nested class access
```

So how does arrayList preserve its data in **deserialization** process by keeping elementData array **transient**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Marking a member `transient` does not mean the field is not getting serialized, only that it is not serialized *automatically* using Java's built-in serialization mechanism for fields.

In case of `ArrayList` serialization is performed by a custom `writeObject` method: [[src]](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java)

```
private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream s)
    throws java.io.IOException {
    // Write out element count, and any hidden stuff
    int expectedModCount = modCount;
    s.defaultWriteObject();
    // Write out size as capacity for behavioural compatibility with clone()
    s.writeInt(size);
    // Write out all elements in the proper order.
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        s.writeObject(elementData[i]);
    }
    if (modCount != expectedModCount) {
        throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
    }
}
```

Deserialization is performed using `readObject`.

Comment: Who initiate the writeObject() call since it is private method?

Comment: `private` is not _strictly_ private:  the Reflection API allows access to `private` methods, and the internal serialization machinery employs reflection to find and call the `writeObject` method even though it is private.